# Get hidden parameter from Bar chart

Tags: jqplot

I am assigning extra hidden parameters to my bar chart.

["R1", 5.01, "india", "maharashtra"];

How can I show these hidden data in my tooltip on highlight

This is the code which I am using to show tooltip, but I am not able to show the hidden data.

```
highlighter: {
             tooltipContentEditor: function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
             return data[3] ;
                },
             show: true
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter in the `tooltipContentEditor` function is a plot object not the data object. You can obtain the data object from it though. Using this modified `tooltipContentEditor` function, you should be able to get the tooltip to display hidden data:

```
highlighter: {
    ...
    tooltipContentEditor: function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {
        // access the data and locate the correct data point based on the series and data point hovered over and return the hidden value from the data at array index 2 (array indexes are 0 based)
        return plot.data[seriesIndex][pointIndex][2];
    }
}
```

In this example the data is as follows (where the third value is the 'hidden' tooltip):

```
[
    ['23-May-08', 578.55, 'A'],
    ['20-Jun-08', 566.5, 'B'],
    ['25-Jul-08', 480.88, 'C'],
    ['22-Aug-08', 509.84, 'D'],
    ['26-Sep-08', 454.13, 'E'],
    ['24-Oct-08', 379.75, 'F']
]
```

I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4n4do6wm/1/) to demonstrate this.